# How should I add some space between the text and the border using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I was messing around with an unordered list to make a semblance of a navigation page, and I've had a problem I can't fix. Each border around the words are very closed in, and I don't have any idea how to make the area inside the borders bigger meaning I want the border to be farther away from the word.

I know it looks horrible, but I'm really just focused on making it work properly rather than making it look good.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!doctype=html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Test Title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="test"> Blah Blah </h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Blog </a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Facebook </a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Twitter </a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> About </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```css
.wrap
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.navitem
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
}

.navitem:hover
{
    color: 339900;
    border-color: 339900;
}
```

Comment: try .navitem class in css with "padding: 5px;"

Comment: The answers will probably fix your immediate problem, but if you want to know more you should probably look up on the `display` property ([W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)). You are styling `inline` items whereas you may have expected to be working with `inline-block` items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have some space between the words and the border, than you need to use `padding` property for that

```css
.navitem {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CkVBe/)

Also, you can write the same thing as `border: 1px solid green;` which is nothing but the `border` shorthand.

---

Also, you told us that you are a [fresher](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fresher#Noun). Make sure you reset the default `margin` and `padding` which are applied by the browser by using

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Or by using [CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) so that your menu styles position stays consistent across the browsers.

---

Lastly, you do not need to call classes on each of your element, you can leave it up to CSS selectors to select them... So get rid of all the classes, and just assign a class to the parent element, and use the selectors below..

Am assigning class to `ul` which is `main_navigation` so now we will select all the first level `li` using

```css
.main_navigation > li {
   /* Target direct child to .main_navigation */
}
```

And to target direct `a` inside those `li` we will use

```css
.main_navigation li a {
    /* Target direct child to .main_navigation > li */
}
```

[**Refactored Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CkVBe/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Just add `padding` in `NavItem`:

```css
.navitem
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 5px 10px; // The first 5px is for Height, and the second 10px is for Width. Adjust it for your needs.
}
```

Comment: `//` is [not a valid comment character sequence in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797790/why-are-some-of-my-css-rules-not-working/34799134#34799134) (only the C-style one is, `/*   */`). This is also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting here. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in your CSS content:

```css
ul li a {
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in your CSS:

```css
ul li a
{
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Or you can set your class as:

```css
.navitem
{
    width: 100px; /* Set width and height as you wish */
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some padding to the list items:

```css
.navitem {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the CSS content with

```css
.navitem {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /* It specified a padding of 5px to top and bottom and 10px to left and right */
}
```

You can also use `padding-top, padding-left, padding-right, padding-bottom` individually also as per your requirement.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/pJg2u/)

Comment: `//` is [not a valid comment character sequence in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797790/why-are-some-of-my-css-rules-not-working/34799134#34799134) (only the C-style one is, `/*   */`). This is also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting here. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```css
.wrap
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 50px;

}

.navitem
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. We may still get it (still not in years): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 1):

In order to manipulate each list-item as a box, you need to put each `<li>` item into a `<div>`. A `<div>` works as a container, or as a box. You can then specify height, width, text alignment, borders, etc. for it. So, your HTML should look like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Test Title </title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" /> -->
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
<h1 class="test"> Blah Blah </h1>
<ul>
    <div class="box">
    <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Blog </a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Facebook </a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> Twitter </a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <li class="navigation"><a class="navitem" href="#"> About </a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Whereas your CSS could be:

```css
.wrap
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

li.navigation
{
    text-align: center;
}

.navitem
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navitem:hover
{
    color: 339900;
    border-color: 339900;
}

div.box
{
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Change anchor display to inline-block and add some padding

```css
.navitem
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;

   display: inline-block;
   padding: 7px 15px;
}
```