# Why are some of my CSS rules not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a nested [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) layout (using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) v4) which changes orientation according to landscape / portrait mode.  A first level `div` (which is placed by Flexbox using the `order` property), `#no`, holds five icons which serve as buttons.  The `order` property doesn't work as I expect on these icons.

If I don't use an `order` property, the icons are laid out in the natural order; however, if I try to use the `order` property to lay them out, it doesn't work.  In [the code](https://jsfiddle.net/lenb/eegvb0j4/), the `info-div` (`order:3`) should be the last element.  It isn't.  I can get the order I want by changing order in the source; however, I would like to clarify my misunderstanding.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
}

#no {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.icon {
  margin: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

button:ACTIVE {
  // feedback on touch modal
  background: aqua;
}

// next is for images
.img {
  width: 8vmin;
}

// stuff living in #no
#info-div1 {
  order: 3;
  -webkit-order: 3;
}

#minus {
  order: 0;
  -webkit-order: 0;
}

#hb2 {
  order: -1;
  -webkit-order: -1;
}

#plus {
  order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
}

#comment-button-div {
  order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #container {
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  }
  #no {
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 10rem;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-order: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #container {
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  }
  #no {
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 10rem;
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
  }
}

</style><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script></head><body><div id="container"><div id='no'><div id='minus' class="icon" title="Not special."><a href="#" id="nHeart"><img class="img icon" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/Not.svg"/></a></div><div id="hb2" title="Login/Register/Uploads/Settings" class="btn-group icon"><div class="dropdown"><img class="dropdown-toggle img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/cogwheel-525702-1.svg" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/><div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item clr" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a><a class="dropdown-item cup" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a><a class="dropdown-item cmore" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a><a class="dropdown-item cpony" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a><a class="dropdown-item cabout" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a></div></div></div><!-- end hb2 --><div id='plus' class="icon" title="Loving it!"><a href="#" id="heart1"><img class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/red-304570-1.svg"/></a></div><div id='comment-button-div' class="icon" title="Click for comments"><a class="comment-page" data-toggle="modal"><img class="img" id='comment-button' src="http://gps-photo.org/images/comments-97860-3.svg"/></a></div><div id='info-div1' class="icon" title='Information'><a class="info-page" data-toggle="modal"><img id="info1" class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/information-39064-2.svg"/></a></div></div></div><!-- jQuery first,
then Bootstrap JS. --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script></body></html>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id='no'>

    <div id='minus' class="icon" title="Not special.">
      <a href="#" id="nHeart">
        <img class="img icon" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/Not.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="hb2" title="Login/Register/Uploads/Settings" class="btn-group icon">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <img class="dropdown-toggle img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/cogwheel-525702-1.svg" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" />
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item clr" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cup" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cmore" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cpony" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cabout" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end hb2 -->
    <div id='plus' class="icon" title="Loving it!">
      <a href="#" id="heart1">
        <img class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/red-304570-1.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id='comment-button-div' class="icon" title="Click for comments">
      <a class="comment-page" data-toggle="modal">
        <img class="img" id='comment-button' src="http://gps-photo.org/images/comments-97860-3.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id='info-div1' class="icon" title='Information'>
      <a class="info-page" data-toggle="modal">
        <img id="info1" class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/information-39064-2.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CSS Commenting: Use `/* ... */`, not `//...` or `<!-- ... -->`

The problem you're having is not related to your flex code.

The problem is you're using ***line comment syntax*** for commenting out text, and this is not valid CSS.

```
button:ACTIVE { // feedback on touch modal
   background: aqua;
}

// next is for images
.img { width: 8vmin; }
```

So you're actually posting invalid code which, instead of commenting out the line, is calling CSS error-handling into play, which kills the next rule. In other words, any rule following your `// text text text` is ignored, just as if you had done this: `xheight: 50px`.

This is why `order` is not working for your icon:

```
// stuff living in #no
#info-div1 {
    order: 3;
    -webkit-order: 3;
}
```

Stick to the standard CSS commenting method. Start a comment with `/*`. End a comment with `*/`.

```css
/* stuff to be commented out */
```

Once you make the adjustments in your code, the `order` property works fine (and, as you might expect, other changes occur, caused by previously ignored code). [See revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eegvb0j4/1/).

Read more about CSS comments here:

- [4. Syntax and basic data types > Section 4.1.9 Comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments) ~ W3C
- [Is it bad practice to comment out single lines of CSS with //?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12298890/3597276)
- [Do double forward slashes direct IE to use specific css?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218808/3597276)
- [Single Line Comments (`//`) in CSS](http://www.xanthir.com/b4U10) ~ Tab Atkins, Jr., CSS Working Group

---

*Lastly, on a separate note:*

You're placing vendor prefixed code *after* the standard unprefixed versions.

```css
#container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;

    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;

    align-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: space-between;
}
```

You should consider reversing this. The unprefixed (W3C) version should go last, so it's always the preferred version in the cascade. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7080605/3597276).