# width in pixels ignoring max-width:100%

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

I have a problem between `width` and `max-width` working in an element with a grandparent flex positioned container.

When I use `width` in pixels with `max-width: 100%` in this element, if the width is bigger than its parent it just ignores the `max-width:100%`. But if for example I use `width: 150%` then the `max-width:100%` does its work.

```css
body{
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}
body:before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
body:after{
  content:"16:9 screen size ratio example";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
#flex-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}
#sidebar{
  min-width:150px;
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
#main-content{
  width:100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid{
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="sidebar"><h2>Sidebar</h2></div>
  <div id="main-content">
    <div class="page">
      <h1>Content page</h1>
      <div class="grid">
        A grid with certain width defined in units and based on the device. Specified width should not exceed its parent width (max-width: 100%).
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br><br>


Should work like this:
<br>
<div style="width:640px;height:360px; border: 2px solid black;background-color:white;">
  <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    640px width parent
    <div style="max-width:100%; width:800px; height:100px; background-color:green;color:white;">
      800px width with max-width:100%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abu7z1uj/6/).

Comment: Max-width always beats width. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: @Paulie_D Should it. Here is the problem, in my example `max-width` doesn't beat `width`. Take a look at the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container (`body`) is `width: 640px`.

The child of `body` (the `#flex-container`) is `width: 100%`. In other words, 640px.

Your left-side flex item (`#sidebar`) is `min-width: 150px`. For argument's sake: `width: 150px`.

Your right-side flex item (`#main-content`) is `width: 100%`. Computing to: 531.989px (reason tbd).

The child of `#main-content` (`.page`) is `width: 100%`. Also, 531.989px

The child of `.page` (`.grid`) is `width: 500px`. This fits well into the parent, with extra space (31.989px) left over.

Your `max-width: 100%` never sees any action. It works, it just isn't called upon.

In your second example, you apply `width: 800px` to the `.grid` equivalent, which is greater than 531.989px, so `max-width: 100%` is called into action.

---

***Flex items minimum size***

Note that by default a flex item will not shrink past the size of its content.

Add `min-width: 0` to `#main-content`.

Explanation: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

***Syntax Errors***

Also note that your [*line commenting syntax*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799134/3597276)...

```
.grid {
  width: 500px; // For some reason this ignores max-width when is defined in units.
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

.... and [*parenthesis around the `flex` property*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)...

```
#sidebar{
  min-width:150px;
  flex(0, 1, 150px);
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
#main-content{
  width:100%;
  flex(1, 1, auto);
  background-color: white;
}
```

are causing significant problems.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/abu7z1uj/4/)

Comment: I updated the snippet setting the `.grid` width to 800px, it is still beating the `max-width` rule. About the `#main-content` width, how can I give it the correct width remaining of its parent? (Dynamically, the snippet dimensions are just an example)

Comment: Instead of setting a `width`, just give `#main-content` a `flex: 1`. This will tell it to consume any remaining space on the line.

Comment: @Michael_B to the rescue ;)