# Why are there extra columns added in CSS Grid when using grid-auto-flow?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning CSS Grid and trying to reproduce some flex behaviour (I know that both are complementary, this is a learning exercise).

The flex example below allows for an undefined number of `div`s to be stacked (undefined in the sense that their number does not impact the CSS part)

```css
#flex {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#flex > div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

I tried to port this to a CSS Grid implementation:

```css
/* updated with correct comment delimiters, thanks @vals */

#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;  /* when something has to be added, be it a column */
  grid-auto-columns: fit-content; /* when a new column is added, its size will be driven by the content. Unfortunately this does not work yet but never mind for now */
  grid-row: auto; /* one row, auto-sized */
}

#grid > div {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

The fact that the width of the cells is not as expected (per the comments) is something I will investigate later, **my main problem is that there are three extra columns, one before each of the expected ones**.

When inspecting the grid, I can see that some of the lines are plain, while others are dotted (I am not sure whether this is an indication of something):

[image]

Are the blanks extra columns?

- if yes: where do they come from?
- if not: are they some kind of padding, and why isn't the column taking all the available space then?

Comment: ` grid-auto-columns: fit-content; ` does not exist you mean  `grid-auto-columns: max-content;` Than it also looks the same :) grid-row: auto also does not exist

Comment: Not sure about why, but you have nbsp in your HTML. Remove them and you are ok.

Comment: @Doomenik: thanks, yes, I had `max-content`in mind (but `fit-content`exists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns). Also `grid-row: auto` exists (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row)

Answer (score 1):

In your container code:

```css
#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;  
  grid-auto-columns: fit-content; 
  grid-row: auto;
}
```

The `grid-row` rule is having no effect. This property applies only to grid items.

You may be wanting `grid-template-rows` or `grid-auto-rows`, which apply to grid containers.

Also, before editing your question, you were using an invalid form of comments in your CSS. That was causing a syntax error.

The problem is explained here:

- [Why are some of my CSS rules not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34797790/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content; 
}

#grid > div {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

At `grid-auto-columns: fit-content;`, you probably meant max-content. `grid-row` is unnecessary.

Also, as mentioned by @vals in the comments, you had `&nbsp;` line breaks.

A good resource to read about grids is at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. As I mentioned in a comment, `fit-content` and `grid-row: auto` are described in the Mozilla docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns).

Comment: @WoJ strange cause mozillas browser does not provide them as autocomplete. Anyway removed it from my answer

Comment: @WoJ did I answered your question ?